# How does Google Maps know my position without using a foreground service?

Tags: android, backgrounding

I've been developing an app that gathers data from a wearable device (connected by Bluetooth). I'd like that data to be stored even when the app's main activity gets destroyed by the Android framework. After some research, I noticed that I had to use a foreground service to do that.

Then, I noticed that google maps sends me notifications about my location (e.g. how was McDonald's, review it), meaning the app communicates my location with Google's servers even when the app's main activity hasn't been launched.

How do they achieve such behavior without the use of foreground services?

Comment: I guess there is a background service that does that, it’s google anyway.

Comment: So you're saying that google developers have access to special APIs of the Android framework?

Comment: Judging from the fact, for example, that google maps expose different features in Maps app, compared to the APi given to other apps, yes.

Comment: i think android framework constantly updates the location if you agreed. app can then pull `lastKnownLocation`  without running a foreground service